# Event call twice for two children

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this HTML:

```
<fieldset class="some_class" data-attr="data">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Some label</label>
</fieldset>
```

I need to send some event after check fieldset data atribute through click on it childrens. So:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var t = $(e.target),
        $t = t.parents('.some_class');
    if (typeof $t.data('attr') !== 'undefined') {
       console.log('test');
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine but this console.log is catching two times, that's bc fieldset have two elements inside - i guess. How to call this event only one time?

Comment: Why don't you bind event directly to the `<fieldset>` element?

Comment: It's firing twice because it's collecting two nodes (from `.parents()`), Although you only test the ***first*** node twice. But I much agree with VisioN; you're making it more difficult for yourself this way.

Comment: @VisioN bc this is only example, i will have much more elements with that kind of data attribute

Comment: I tried to reproduce, but console.log is called one time on my browser (latest chrome on windows).